# Black Console after automated Debian UEFI install

Tags: linux, console, debian, vmware, uefi

I try to build a reproducible automated build environment based on Debian 8.1 Jessie.
I created a boot iso image based on a netinstall image and put a preseed.cfg file in int for automatic installation.
I managed to get it bootable with BIOS and UEFI and can install a KDE Developer Debian in VMWare Workstation 11 fully automated.

I have also a server iso image to install a debian Server with Jenkins, both with BIOS and UEFI Boot.

But after the installation, the Version with UEFI Boot shows a black Screen when started.

I can blindly log in, start the gui with "startx" and see my installed xfce desktop. When i quit xfce the console is usable and visible.

I tried suggested bootparameters "nomodeset" and "vga=Linux" that i found with google to no avail.

I also tried to debug the boot prozess, to find out which command leads to a blank screen, but i did not find the right place to delay the processes at bootup so i can see when the messages dissapear (quiet bootparameter was removed :-)

I also tried to reset the console to no avail.

Can anybode point me to a tool that does the same "switching" like X so the console is useable?

Can anybody give me some hints how to debug the bootprocess to find out which command is causing this behaviour?

I dont want to install X because this should be a headless server system later.

Answer (score -2):

I managed to get my system to boot using the kernel command line modprobe.blacklist=vmwgfx, or placing 'blacklist vmwgfx' in /etc/modprobe.d/*.conf

I assume it is some bug in the vmwgfx module, however as this workaround works for me I have no immediate need to investigate further.